# MonogoDB search for name of array in object

Tags: mongodb

I am super stumped on this one:

I am trying to write a query to find all users that belong to a specific organization(in this case org "uPpy4M7H3aY5rYbiz"). In the database each user has roles(an object of arrays). The arrays are named by the org id.

I thought `db.user.find( {"roles": {"uPpy4M7H3aY5rYbiz": { "$exists": true } }} )` should work but its not. I couldn't find much about searching for fields.

Here is an example of one user in the database: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at least for your specific query this should work

`db.user.find( {"roles.uPpy4M7H3aY5rYbiz": { "$exists": true } } )`